# Make a offline Search using JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am making a Estate  site will be OFFLINE. I have done most of the site but stuck at how to search using JSON (I have never used JSON before). I have these search options in which user can search different properties with different options . I know how to link the JSON file with html but dont know how to link search button and JSON file so when user chooses different option they can get result depending on their filter option.once again the search will be OFFLINE.

[link to code snippet of form and json file](http://jsfiddle.net/6y8fmpw0/)

Code Snippet of form

```
</form>
<h3>Find Your Property</h3>
 <fieldset>
 <label for="Type">Type:</label>   
 <select>
  <option>House</option>
  <option>Flat/Apartments</option>
  <option>Bungalow</option>
   <option>Land</option>
```

```
 <label for="Price Range">Price Range:</label>
  <select>
  <option>0</option>
     <option>50,000</option>
     <option>100,000</option>
     <option>150,000</option>
     <option>200,000</option>
  </select>

  to:
  <select>
  <option>50,000</option>
     <option>100,000</option>
     <option>150,000</option>
     <option>200,000</option>
     <option>250,000</option>
     <option>300,000 </option>
     <option>350,000 </option>
     <option>400,000 </option>
     <option>500,000 or more</option>
  </select>

    <label for="Bedroom">Bedroom(s):</label> 
  <select>
  <option>No min</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>

  </select>
  <select>
     <option>No max</option>
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>3</option>
  </select></fieldset>

    </fieldset><button Class="btn"type="button">Show me houses</button></fieldset>




                        </form>
```

for JSON file please check the link I posted.

Comment: JSON is JavaScript Object Notation so you should understand how java script object is structured first.

Comment: I know its not homework service , buts its a helping community which is why I posted a question. I just want to know how to connect JSON file(which can be seen in jsfiddle link) to the search button in my form.Any help would be great.

Comment: @mkoryak this what i have done in my html to link the json file                                                              <script>
  $.getJSON('properties.json', function(data) {
        var output="<ul>";
        for (var i in data.properties) {
            output+="<li>" + data.properties[i].type +"</li>";
        }

       
  });
    </script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to filter the array of properties. Let's assume you store your javascript object about properties in variable data, then data.properties is an array of properties and you can filter this array based on the selection criteria like type, price range and bedroom nubers range.

And to make dom manipulation easier, jquery is used in the solution.

```
var getProperties = function(type, minPrice, maxPrice, minBed, maxBed) {
    if (typeof minBed === "undefined") { minBed = 0; }
    if (typeof maxBed === "undefined") { maxBed = Number.MAX_VALUE; }

    return data.properties.filter(function (elem) {
        var expType = type.indexOf(elem.type) >= 0;
        var expPrice = elem.price >= minPrice && (maxPrice === Number.MAX_VALUE ? true : elem.price <= maxPrice);
        var expBedrooms = (maxBed === Number.MAX_VALUE) ? elem.bedrooms >= minBed : elem.bedrooms >= minBed && elem.bedrooms <= maxBed;
        return expType && expPrice && expBedrooms;
    });
}

$("#showHouses").click(function () {
    var type = $("#type").val();
    var minPrice = parseInt($("#minPrice").val().replace(",", ""));
    var maxPrice = $("#maxPrice").val().indexOf("more") >= 0 ? Number.MAX_VALUE : parseInt($("#maxPrice").val().replace(",", ""));
    var minBed = isNaN( parseInt($("#minBed").val()))? 0 : parseInt($("#minBed").val());
    var maxBed = isNaN(parseInt($("#maxBed").val())) ? Number.MAX_VALUE : parseInt($("#maxBed").val());

    var properties = getProperties(type, minPrice, maxPrice, minBed, maxBed);
    $("#placeHolder").text(JSON.stringify(properties));
});
```

[DEMO in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bruceyang/6y8fmpw0/21/)

Comment: Thanks alot @user2466202 for this clear answer. One more question as I saw the search result would display as alert in code. what if I would like to show in my html page,would the  code be something  like this document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=data. properties. (ofcourse I would make div tag with placeholder ID). thanks alot for your help so far and thanks in advance for any further help.

Comment: P.J I've modified code to show data in a container with id placeHolder. But I guess instead to show raw data, probably you need to format the data properly, like adding some styles.

Comment: thanks for that. Is it possible you can guide me how to format the data to view it properly in html as it's a JSON file because formatting Json file is not possible as it has to structured in that way(on the top i havent use json before). I will probably mess up the whole code. if you could show an example , then i can pull it off from there. thanks alot once again, really appreciate your help.

Comment: P.J Sure, I will do it tomorrow because tonight I need to take a 14-hour flight back home.

Comment: is it possible sir can you do it now,? @user2466202